# Climbing the Leaderboard Solution using BinarySearch but it fails 8/12 test cases

Tags: java, algorithm

When solving implementation in Hackerrank, I meet one challenge :
[Climbing the Leaderboard](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem).

Here is the summary how this work:

[image]

At the first look I see that it contains two Integer List: current leaderboard and new user scores list in order already but current leaderboard contains some repeated element and new user scores list is not. So I choose the solution like this:

1. I move the element from current leaderBoard to new Leader Board ( still in order but not contains any repeated element)
2. I loop through each score in new user scores list and perform the binary searching in the new Leader Board to find the position for new score.
3. From what I estimate this solution will have the time complexity is O(nlog(n))

Here is my code:

```
    public static List<Integer> climbingLeaderboard(List<Integer> ranked, List<Integer> player) {
    // Write your code here
        List<Integer> newLeadRank =  new ArrayList<>();
        
        List<Integer> newRankedBoard = new ArrayList<>();
        newRankedBoard.add(ranked.get(0));
        
        for(int i = 1 ; i < ranked.size() ; i++){
            if(ranked.get(i-1) != ranked.get(i)){
                newRankedBoard.add(ranked.get(i));
            }
        }        
        for(Integer point : player){
            int newRanked = findNewRankedPosition(newRankedBoard, point);
            newLeadRank.add(newRanked);
        }
        return newLeadRank;
    }
    
    public static int findNewRankedPosition(List<Integer> newRankedBoard, int playerPoint){
        int last = newRankedBoard.size()-1;
        int first = 0;
        return binarySearch(newRankedBoard, first, last, playerPoint);
    }
    
    public static int binarySearch(List<Integer> newRankedBoard, int first, int last, int key){
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        int newRanked = 1;
        while(first <= last){
            if(newRankedBoard.get(mid) > key){
                
                if(mid + 1 < newRankedBoard.size() && newRankedBoard.get(mid+1) < key){
                    
                    newRanked = mid + 2;
                    break;
                }else if(mid + 1 == newRankedBoard.size()){
                    newRanked = mid + 2;
                    break;
                }
                return binarySearch(newRankedBoard, mid + 1, last, key);  
            }else if(newRankedBoard.get(mid) < key){
                if(mid - 1 > 0 && newRankedBoard.get(mid-1) > key){
                    newRanked = mid + 1;
                    break;
                }else if(mid - 1 == 0 && newRankedBoard.get(0) < key){
                    newRanked = 1;
                    break;
                }
                return binarySearch(newRankedBoard, first, mid - 1, key);
            }else if(newRankedBoard.get(mid) == key){
                newRanked = mid + 1;
                break; 
            }
        }
        return newRanked ;
    }
}
```

I pass all the example test case and 4/12 test case. But fail another 8/12 test case. Can you take a look and tell me where I am wrong and how I can enhance my code?

Here is one test case I failed:

200

998 995 995 991 989 989 984 979 968 964 955 955 947 945 942 934 933 930 928 927 918 916 905 900 898 895 895 895 892 887 882 881 878 876 872 872 858 856 846 844 839 823 808 806 804 800 799 794 793 789 784 772 766 765 764 762 762 759 757 751 747 745 738 725 720 708 706 703 699 697 693 691 690 685 682 677 662 661 656 648 642 641 640 634 632 625 623 618 618 617 601 601 600 591 585 583 578 552 550 550 546 543 539 509 505 503 503 494 486 474 472 472 472 468 467 464 439 438 434 434 427 421 420 405 399 395 392 388 386 384 377 374 368 356 350 344 342 341 337 331 298 296 296 294 290 260 259 248 245 244 244 233 228 215 211 210 206 202 201 189 186 181 178 168 163 162 161 159 151 147 143 142 142 141 139 132 130 128 125 125 120 112 111 95 92 91 88 81 69 66 63 48 44 20 18 17 14 8 1 1

20

18 31 38 126 152 170 198 199 202 243 369 376 376 408 560 572 614 665 666 942

The expected Result should be:

177
176
176
162
153
148
144
144
142
136
119
118
118
110
89
89
83
70
70
12

My Result is:

194
193
193
179
169
164
160
160
158
152
133
132
132
124
98
98
91
77
77
15

Comment: What test cases are failing? Please provide the code to initialise your input data such that it reproduces the problem.

Comment: An obvious error. your program would fail if the `ranked` list is empty

Answer (score 0):

you did everything correct except for this line:

```
if(ranked.get(i-1) != ranked.get(i)){
```

it should instead be:

```
if(!ranked.get(i-1).equals(ranked.get(i))){
```

The "ranked" list has items that are Integer Objects and not primitive int and so we cannot use simple logical "!=" as that will just compare the reference but not value; instead use Object's "equals" method.

FWIW, you can also use Arrays class binarySearch to do this.

```
    public static List<Integer> climbingLeaderboard1(List<Integer> ranked, List<Integer> player) {
    
    
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer[] rankedArr = ranked.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    int length =  rankedArr.length;   
    Integer[] denseRankArr = new Integer[length+1];
    
    denseRankArr[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<length;i++ ){
        if(rankedArr[i].equals(rankedArr[i-1]))
            denseRankArr[i]=denseRankArr[i-1];
        else
            denseRankArr[i]=denseRankArr[i-1] +1;  
                     
    }
    denseRankArr[length] = denseRankArr[length-1] +1;
    
    for(Integer play: player) {
        
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(rankedArr, play, (a,b)->b-a);
        
        if(index <0)
            index = (index * -1) -1;
        
        result.add(denseRankArr[index]);
    }
    
    
    return result;
    }
```